# How do I use SSDT with VS2015

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-2015

I am using Windows 7 SP1.
I have SQL Server 2012 installed along with Visual Studio Community 2015.

The SQL Server 2012 installation has always forced me to use VS2010 Shell to launch SQL Server Data Tools.

I recently installed an update through the NuGet Package Manager in VS2015 which included SSDT.  I was hoping that this would enable me to use SSDT with VS2015.  However it still launches with VS2010.

My question is:  How do I used SQL Server Data Tools with Visual Studio 2015?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Dbproj, ssis, msas? What version of SQL?

Comment: I'm trying to create an SSIS package.  I'm using SQL Server 2012 (v11.0.2100.60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest release (Feb 2016) is the first release of SSDT that can target different versions of SSIS so you can now target 2012 from visual studio 2015:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/03/07/ssdt-preview-update-feb-2016/

It is still in preview though so you will need to download the pre-release bits:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

or wait a month or so for the RTM release.

I usually use the pre-release builds and they are normally pretty solid but each environment is different :)

ed